# Local uniformity implies Riemann integrability

Tags: complex-analysis

---

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $f_{n}:G\to \mathbf{C}, n\in \mathbf{N}$, continuous and integrable and let $f=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}$ be locally uniform in $G$. Then $f$ is continuous and integrable in $G$.

---

**Proof (old version, new is below)**

Assume integrable to mean Riemann integrable. Then let
$$
\begin{align*}
T &:= \inf \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})\cdot \sup_{x_k-1 \lt x\lt x_{k}} f(x), \\
t &:= \sup \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})\cdot \inf_{x_k-1\lt x \lt x_{k}} f(x), \\
\epsilon_{n} & = \sup_{x\in G}{\ | f_{n}(x)-f(x)|}
\end{align*}
$$

so

$$f_{n}(x) - \epsilon_{n} \le f(x) \le f_{n}(x) + \epsilon_{n} \ \forall x\in G, n\in \mathbf{N}$$  and with $b,a \in G$

$$\Rightarrow \int f_{n}(x)\,dx - \epsilon_{n}(b-a) \le t \le T \le \int f_{n}(x)\,dx + \epsilon_{n}(b-a) \ \forall n \in \mathbf{N}$$

and hence

$$0\le T-t \le 2\epsilon_{n}(b-a) $$

now  local uniform convergence $\Leftrightarrow  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\ \sup\limits_{x\in G}\ |f_{n}-f| = 0$.

it follows that :

for $n\to \infty : T=t$

So $f$ is Riemann integrable and thus also continuous on $G$.

---

**Proof (new version)**

We show that $f$ is continuous in $G$.

Let $t_{0} \in G$, then by premise there is a environment $U$ in $t_{0}$ so that $f_{n}$ restricted to $$G\cap U$$ converges uniformly to $f$ restricted to $G\cap U$. Then all $f_{n}$ restricted to $G\cap U$ in $t_{0}$ are continuous (because continuity is a local property). Therefore $f$ restricted to $G \cap U$ is continuous in $t_{0}$. Again because of the local property of continuity it follows that $f$ is therefore also continuous in $t_{0}$.

$f$ is integrable on $G$ because it is continuous $G$.

---

Is this proof (new version) fine? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I tried to fix some of your formulas and added some free space in order to make it easier to read. Please check that I didn't change the intentions. I didn't understand two things: 1) The definition for local uniform convergence you give is uniform convergence on $G$. 2) the last part "So $f$ is Riemann integrable" (would be fine if 1) is ok) "and thus also continuous" (why is that?)

Comment: A few more things: I would show that $f$ is continuous first. There seems to be a condition missing in your theorem: it could happen that $\int f_n \to \infty$. For example, take $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ to be continuous, constant equal to $1$ on $[-n,n]$ and zero outside $[-(n+1),n+1)]$. Then each $f_n$ is integrable, and the sequence $f_n$ converges to the constant function $1$ locally uniformly, which is not integrable.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for editing and the feedback. I appreciate it.